# Install the glibc report configure LD_LIBRARY_PATH error

Tags: linux, glibc

Install the glibc-2.17 on redhat, download, unzip, configure then report  LD_LIBRARY_PATH error:

```
checking for gawk... gawk
checking version of gawk... 3.1.7, ok
checking for nm... nm
checking for autoconf... autoconf
checking whether autoconf works... no
configure: WARNING:
*** These auxiliary programs are missing or incompatible versions: autoconf
*** some features will be disabled.
*** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.
checking LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable... contains current directory
configure: error:
*** LD_LIBRARY_PATH shouldn't contain the current directory when
*** building glibc. Please change the environment variable
*** and run configure again.
```

Check my environment of LD_LIBRARY_PATH, the following:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/public/software/apps/boost-1.59.0/include:/public/software/apps/boost-1.59.0/lib:/usr/local/cudnn/cuda/lib64/:/usr/loca
l/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/lib:/public/software//mpi/openmpi/1.8.5/intel/lib:/opt/gridview//pbs/dispatcher/lib:/public/soft
ware//compiler/intel/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/lib/intel64:/public/software//compiler/intel/composer_xe_2015.2.164
/mkl/lib/intel64::/usr/local/lib64:/usr/local/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib:/public/home/chensu/lib:/public/home/chensu/lib/bin:/p
ublic/software/compiler/gnu/mpc-1.0.2/lib:/public/software/compiler/gnu/mpfr-3.1.3/lib:/public/software/compiler/gnu/gmp
-5.0.1/lib:/public/software/compiler/intel/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/lib/mic:/public/software/compiler/intel/compo
ser_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/lib/intel64:/public/home/chensu/lib/boost_1_61_0:/public/home/chensu/lib/boost_1_61_0/stage/l
ib:/public/home/chensu/lib/sparsehash-master:/public/home/chensu/lib/sparsehash/include/google:/public/home/chensu/lib/s
parsehash/include/sparsehash
```

Does anybody know how to set it?  I will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing :: with : (only single column) in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 2):

I have also come across this issuse. According to [comment here](https://github.com/Linuxbrew/legacy-linuxbrew/issues/807#issuecomment-193881547), it is because your LD_LIBRARY_PATH has an empty entry (in `mkl/lib/intel64::`). When an empty entry is found in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, ld will start finding library from current directory.

You need to somehow remove that empty entry from LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove your current directory from LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable

Comment: there is no current directory in LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable

Comment: $ pwd
/public/home/chensu/others/Guicai/glibc-2.17

Comment: print 'echo $PATH' and 'echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH' and share the output

Answer (score 1):

From my attempts to install glibc-2.32, I discovered that `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should not have a trailing `:`.

Answer (score -1):

```
configure: WARNING:
*** These auxiliary programs are missing or incompatible versions: autoconf
*** some features will be disabled.
*** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.
checking LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable... contains current directory
configure: error:
*** LD_LIBRARY_PATH shouldn't contain the current directory when
*** building glibc. Please change the environment variable
*** and run configure again.
```

[chensu@admin1 build]$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
/public/software/apps/boost-1.59.0/include:/public/software/apps/boost-1.59.0/lib:/public/software/apps/boost-1.59.0/include:/public/software/apps/boost-1.59.0/lib:/usr/local/cudnn/cuda/lib64/:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/lib:/public/software/mpi/openmpi/1.8.5/intel/lib:/opt/gridview/pbs/dispatcher/lib:/public/software/compiler/intel/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/lib/intel64:/public/software/compiler/intel/composer_xe_2015.2.164/mkl/lib/intel64::/usr/local/lib64:/usr/local/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib:/public/home/chensu/lib:/public/home/chensu/lib/bin:/public/software/compiler/gnu/mpc-1.0.2/lib:/public/software/compiler/gnu/mpfr-3.1.3/lib:/public/software/compiler/gnu/gmp-5.0.1/lib:/public/software/compiler/intel/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/lib/mic:/public/software/compiler/intel/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/lib/intel64:/public/home/chensu/lib/boost_1_61_0:/public/home/chensu/lib/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib:/public/home/chensu/lib/sparsehash-master:/public/home/chensu/lib/sparsehash/include/google:/public/home/chensu/lib/sparsehash/include/sparsehash:/public/home/chensu/lib:/public/home/chensu/lib/bin:/public/software/compiler/gnu/mpc-1.0.2/lib:/public/software/compiler/gnu/mpfr-3.1.3/lib:/public/software/compiler/gnu/gmp-5.0.1/lib:/public/software/compiler/intel/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/lib/mic:/public/software/compiler/intel/composer_xe_2015.2.164/compiler/lib/intel64:/public/home/chensu/lib/boost_1_61_0:/public/home/chensu/lib/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib:/public/home/chensu/lib/sparsehash-master:/public/home/chensu/lib/sparsehash/include/google:/public/home/chensu/lib/sparsehash/include/sparsehash
```

[chensu@admin1 build]$ pwd

```
/public/home/chensu/others/Guicai/temp/glibc-2.17/build
```